# Laravel make:auth css stylesheet

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5.3

I made authentication example page with *php artisan make:auth*. 
[example page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cewQF.png) If i make changes in css stylesheet nothing is happening. Page is looking same all time. Css stylesheet is located in \public\css folder.

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/app.css') }}">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-    toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Branding Image -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    &nbsp;
                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                                        onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        Logout
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    @yield('content')
</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.css is blank

app.scss

```
// Fonts
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600);

// Variables
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

_variables.scss

```
// Body
$body-bg: #f5f8fa;

// Borders
$laravel-border-color: darken($body-bg, 10%);
$list-group-border: $laravel-border-color;
$navbar-default-border: $laravel-border-color;
$panel-default-border: $laravel-border-color;
$panel-inner-border: $laravel-border-color;

// Brands
$brand-primary: #3097D1;
$brand-info: #8eb4cb;
$brand-success: #2ab27b;
$brand-warning: #cbb956;
$brand-danger:  #bf5329;

// Typography
$font-family-sans-serif: "Raleway", sans-serif;
$font-size-base: 14px;
$line-height-base: 1.6;
$text-color: #636b6f;

// Navbar
$navbar-default-bg: #fff;

// Buttons
$btn-default-color: $text-color;

// Inputs
$input-border: lighten($text-color, 40%);
$input-border-focus: lighten($brand-primary, 25%);
$input-color-placeholder: lighten($text-color, 30%);

// Panels
$panel-default-heading-bg: #fff;
```

Comment: We need to see your code to figure what the problem is

Comment: @Birdman ok i added code but this is simple code generated by php artisan make:auth command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are talking about editing the `app.css` file or a new custom one.

If `app.css` gets overwritten by the pre-processor (normally shoudn't), you can always create a new css file in `public/css/my-styles.css` and load it in your view:

```
<!-- Styles --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/app.css') }}"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/my-styles.css') }}">
```

Make sure to use greater specificity on your css rules to overwrite any predefined settings or use `!important` when you have too.

Also clearing your browser's cache (or using private mode, like Chrome's Incognito) will make sure that your are seeing your current css settings and not some cached content.

Comment: Thanks for help. Clearing browser's cache helped.

Comment: Cache is a pain sometimes.. Glad I've helped!

Answer (score 2):

From https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend#writing-css:

> You can compile your SASS files to plain CSS using Laravel Mix. The
>   npm run dev command will process the instructions in your
>   webpack.mix.js file.

So execute:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you very much